# HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after

Tags: java, database-connection, connection-pooling, jooq, hikaricp

I'm using HikariCP 2.4.7 for connection pool. Everything is fine just after starting the application but after some time without invoking `getConnection()` I get this error when I'm trying to `getConnection()`:

```
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 42734ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:555)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:188)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:147)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:99)
    at pl.airly.database.ComplexOperations.getSensorDataFromArea(ComplexOperations.java:310)
    at pl.airly.database.ComplexOperations.getMeasurementsInAreaWithinTimeFrame(ComplexOperations.java:201)
    at pl.airly.ResponseGenerator.getResponseAdequateToRequest(ResponseGenerator.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor24.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

During startup I'm initializing `HikariDataSource`:

```
hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
hikariDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
hikariDataSource.setUsername(DATABASE_USER_NAME);
hikariDataSource.setPassword(DATABASE_PASSWORD);
hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl(DATABASE_URL);
hikariDataSource.setLeakDetectionThreshold(5000);
```

And then I'm using it like this:

```
try(java.sql.Connection conn = Connection.hikariDataSource.getConnection()) {
            Record1 record1 = DSL.using(conn).select(SENSOR.ID) //jOOQ
                    .from(SENSOR)
                    .where(SENSOR.ID.equal(1))
                    .limit(1)
                    .fetchOne();
            Debug.println(record1.getValue(0).toString());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

What am I doing wrong? How to troubleshoot this problem?

**Edit:**

Adding this solves the problem:

```
hikariDataSource.setIdleTimeout(60000);
hikariDataSource.setConnectionTimeout(60000);
hikariDataSource.setValidationTimeout(3000);
hikariDataSource.setLoginTimeout(5);
hikariDataSource.setMaxLifetime(60000);
```

It may be something connected with the server closing connections before HikariCP does but I'm not sure. Any comment on this would be appreciated.

Comment: were u able to debug and narrow down the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I guess it could be the server closing connections before HikariCP does, however, a while after this problem occurred to me a decision was made to handle the connection in another way.

Comment: You are using a connection pool (HikariPool) but with "try(java.sql.Connection conn = Connection.hikariDataSource.getConnection())" (The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement) you close the connection after the "Debug.println". Maybe that could be a problem.

Comment: Could not delete my comment above - I thought you are using a try-with-resources statement which closes the connection but the Hikari implementation just release the connection back in the pool if you call "close".

Answer (score 0):

I start by saying than i am not a Java programmer, you can try to close jOOQ DSL also:

```
try(java.sql.Connection conn = Connection.hikariDataSource.getConnection()) {
        try (Record1 record1 = DSL.using(conn).select(SENSOR.ID)) {
                .from(SENSOR)
                .where(SENSOR.ID.equal(1))
                .limit(1)
                .fetchOne();
        Debug.println(record1.getValue(0).toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: He is using a try-with-resources which is automatically closing any AutoClosable